# Proof about sequence and subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

I found the next exercise and its respective solution while studying calculus.

> Let $(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence. Suppose that every subsequence $({x_n}_k)$ has a "sub-subsequence" $({{x_n}_k}_j)$ that converges to $0$. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=0$

Proof:

> Suppose that $x_n \not\to 0$. Then, there is an $\varepsilon _0>0$ such that, for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$ $$|x_n|\geq\varepsilon_0$$, for some $n\geq N$.

> Then, it's possible to construct a subsquence $({x_n}_k)$ such that $|{x_n}_k|\geq\varepsilon_0>0$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

> This subsequence $({x_n}_k)$ cannot have any subsequence that converges to $0$ (contradiction).

My questions are: Why can we affirm that it's possible to construct a subsequence $({x_n}_k)$ such that $|{x_n}_k|\geq\varepsilon_0>0$, for every natural number $k$? And why can we affirm that the subsequence $({x_n}_k)$ cannot have any subsequence that converges to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\ \exists \ n\ge N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $|x_{n}|\ge \epsilon_0$

So for $N=1,\exists \ n_1\ge 1\in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $|x_{n_1}|\ge \epsilon_0$

For  $N=n_1+1,\exists \ n_2\ge n_1+1>n_1\in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $|x_{n_2}|\ge \epsilon_0$

Inductively we have $n_1<n_2<...$ and $|x_{n_k}|\ge \epsilon_0$

If $x_{n_k}$ had a subsequence $x_{nkl}\to0$ then for $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$ there would be an element of $x_{kn}$ with length $<\epsilon_0$ contradiction